# How to avoid short-lived clone of String key when using HashMap Entries?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I've written this working code:

```
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Serialize)]
struct Grid64Row {
    ...
    cell: String, 
    ...
}
...
    let mut rows_by_cell: HashMap::<String, Vec<Grid64Row>> = HashMap::new();
    for row in rows {
        match rows_by_cell.entry(row.cell.clone()) {
            Entry::Vacant(e) => { e.insert(vec![row]); },
            Entry::Occupied(mut e) => { e.get_mut().push(row); }
        }
    }
```

As far as I can see, I need to `clone()` the `row.cell` `String`.  The compiler agrees, if I remove the `.clone()`, I get:

```
 error[E0382]: use of partially moved value: `row`
  --> foobar/src/main.rs:97:49
   |
96 |         match rows_by_cell.entry(row.cell) {
   |                                  -------- value partially moved here
97 |             Entry::Vacant(e) => { e.insert(vec![row]); },
   |                                                 ^^^ value used here after partial move
   |
   = note: partial move occurs because `row.cell` has type `std::string::String`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
```

Is there a way to work around this short-lived clone?  (I can't see why '.entry()' needs to take a `String` rather than an `&str`, but even that would still have borrowing issues.)

Comment: I don't think there's a way to avoid the clone with the stdlib. The hashbrown crate has a `raw_entry()` API that might be able to do that.

Comment: It's not short lived in the `Vacant` case, it gets added to the map.

Comment: @cafce25 Thanks for pointing that out.  If you turn this into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @user4815162342 std also has `raw_entry()`, but it is unstable.

Comment: There is an easy workaround, but it has a (very negligible) runtime overhead and a slight change in the signatures, which would be turning a `String` into a `Rc<str>`. `Rc<str>` is also clonable like `String`, but the clone is `O(1)` (it's like a pointer copy). It will prevent you from mutating the string.

Comment: Is there a more limited version of HashMap which doesn't store the keys themselves, just the fixed-length hashes of them?  This would then not need ownership, but as a trade-off, could not enumerate its own keys.

Comment: @fadedbee this wouldn't be a hashmap at all. It could easily return values from the wrong key, if they happened to have the same hash. You need the key value in there so you can compare with `Eq`.

Comment: @PeterHall Interesting, are there no 256 or 512 bit hash algorithms which have good enough collision resistance, e.g. SHA3 or Blake3?

Comment: If you use 256-bit sha as index directly your table is going to be too big (~1.15e77 * word-size bits), of course you can just use the SHA3 of your actual data as key in a regular hashmap.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the returned `Entry` has to be able to create a new entry in the `HashMap` for the `Entry::Vacant` case, therefore without additional constraints like `Clone` or `ToOwned` it has to take the owned version of `T`, not just a reference.

Comment: You make it sound this is an inevitability, but this restriction doesn't _have_ to be there. For example, you could imagine a second method: `fn entry_ref<Q>(&mut self, key: &Q) where K: Borrow<Q> + Clone, Q: Hash + Eq + ?Sized`. This would itself call `clone()`, but only when needed.

Comment: @PeterHall You're right in principle, but your description is still somewhat lacking - calling `key.clone()` would give you a clone of `Q` (or a copy of the reference if `Q` is not `Clone`), whereas you want a `K` constructed out of `&Q`. This could be done using `ToOwned` which looks like it allows that - see e.g. [this comment](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1769#issuecomment-302930147) for an example. This kind of thing has been tried before and didn't materialize, I suspect with good reasons.

Comment: @PeterHall You don't have to imagine, [it's there is hashbrown](https://docs.rs/hashbrown/latest/hashbrown/struct.HashMap.html#method.entry_ref) (with the same name, albeit with a different signature, and it's a candidate for std.

Comment: Well it is an inevitability if you don't want to add additional constrains. It also means you always have to clone in `insert` wether you have something owned to begin with or not. @PeterHall

Comment: @cafce25 If you are cloning it yourself anyway, the extra `Clone` constraint doesn't seem like a very onerous addition...

Comment: @user4815162342 I put the `Clone` constraint on `K`, not `Q`...

Comment: @cafce25 But you are right. The hashbrown implementation is clearly better. My comment was only intended as an example to show that it was possible, not the best possible solution.

Comment: @PeterHall True, but the point was is that in `entry_ref()` don't *have* a `K` key to clone. Instead, you need a way to arrive from `Q` to `K`, at which point you don't need to `clone()` the `K` to begin with.